# Magento 2 Move delivery time below add-to-cart-button

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, addtocart, remove-block

I want delivery time shown after add-to-cart-button. I have already have custom `catalog_product_view.xml` with this entries:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
    <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.addto"/>
    <move element="product.attributes" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price"/>
    <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
```

Please see the screenshot for an explanation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
  // add your custom code via block file.
</referenceContainer>
```

**I hope its work for you.**